# Merge 2 tables by date in r

Tags: r

I want to merge 2 tables which contain the following variables:

> Key   Date   Summary         <---table 1
>
> Key   Date   Variable_1      <---table 2

And I want to have

> Key   Date   Variable_1

1 Key may contain more than 1 value of Variable_1, and I want to match within the following timeline:

```
----------------|--------|--------------------
1 month before     Now       6 months later
```

I am now using the function data.table. Is there any solution to solve such problem? Thank you!

Sample data:

> Key...Date..........Summary
>
> 001...1/5/2017....High risk
>
> 002...7/2/2017....Low risk
>
> 003...4/3/2017....Moderate risk
>
> Key...Date..........Variable_1
>
> 001...29/3/2017.....6.1
>
> 001...6/7/2017.......6.5
>
> 002...1/2/2017.......7.0
>
> 002...3/3/2017.......7.2
>
> 003...1/3/2017.......6.8
>
> 003...6/9/2017.......7.7

The results I want are as follow:

> Key...Date.........Variable_1
>
> 001...1/5/2017....6.5
>
> 002...7/2/2017....7.2
>
> 003...4/3/2017....6.8

Comment: please provide example data? Have you tried to `merge` or dplyr`s join functionalities?

Comment: I have try to use the function df2[df1, roll = TRUE/FALSE/'nearest'] but the outcome is not what I want, and I have not tried to used function merge
Example data are as follow:
>Key      Date          Summary
>001    1/5/2017       High risk

>Key      Date          Variable_1
>001    29/3/2017      6.1
>001    6/7/2017        6.5

For this case, I want to obtain the following results:
>Key       Date        Variable_1
>001    1/5/2017       6.5

Comment: Like @Jimbou suggested, can you provide examples of the 2 initial tables and of the expected output table?

Comment: There are some examples here, thank you